# Sequence in superscript

Tags: symbols, built-in-symbols, input

The code `DisplayForm@SuperscriptBox[a,b,c]` makes a invalid box.  It still renders like $a^b$, but it's red with an error message (as it should be).

[image: error]

That being said, I can type <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to get something visually like $a^{b,c}$.

[image: semi valid]

Is there a way in which this shape of symbols has a valid symbolic representation?  I.e. is there a pattern which could match it?  When you use it in any pieces of code, there is no output.

I'm aware that I can use a myriad of other things; the closest one in my mind is lists as powers.  I don't want to type that; I want sequences as powers.

Curiously enough, there's a string-box way of typing this:

> \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\),\(b,c\)]\)

Comment: I suppose a satisfying negative answer would involve an explanation of the lack of correspondence between symbolic boxes vs string-encoded boxes

Comment: Does `Superscript[a, Row[{b, c}, ","]]` do what you want?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using it as syntax to type some equations quicker, like Christoffel symbols.  So I'll have to make use of copy/paste or custom inputs to type that out; was hoping to have a way to use standard keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I suppose a similar thing would be the result of `a` `ctrl-6` `ctrl-9` `b,c`, i.e. Power[a,TextCell["b,c"]].  I'd have to do string parsing to work with the equation after typing, but that's a fine tradeoff I think.  OTOH inputaliases aren't that hard.